# Put a div on top of an image exactly in position with object-fit

Tags: html, css, image

I want to put a div on top of this image(a cupcake).
[image]

For example, I want to put my div on top of the red cherry, like this [image]

Because my image has a dynamic width and height and I am using `object-fit: cover;` in my css,
so the div position has to move accordingly when my image resize.

If my image has fixed dimension, using `position: absolute;` will do the job. However, with `object-fit: cover;` in my image, my image is goanna move around with user resizes. How to make my div appear in the exact position when resizes happen?

Thanks. And if my question is messy and you cannot understand, please let me know because I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: you will have to figure out the left and top as a percentage of the image and use  that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, to get the accurate top and center positioning of div you can use `CSS` `calc() function`.

```css
#box{
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
#box > .bx{
  position:absolute;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background:#111;
  top:5%;
  left:calc(100% - 60%);
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
<div class="bx">Text</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mj25.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: @Jeffrey C Do accept or upvote the solution if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt think of this approach, how silly me.

Comment: Welcome @JeffreyC :-)

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. What you have to do is: use percent values for positioning, for example:

```
.my_cover_div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    top: 5%;
}
```

For centering at exact point, [this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) may be useful.